# Why use __weak __typeof__(task) weakTask = task in AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am studying the `AFNetworking` (3.0) source codes.
I notice that in `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate`'s method

```
- (void)setupProgressForTask:(NSURLSessionTask *)task {
       __weak __typeof__(task) weakTask = task;
    ...}
```

uses the `weak` task. I know the below code block will hold strong reference to task, that means `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate` will strong hold task if not use weak task.
But the task do not strong hold `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate`, there is no circular reference. 
So why there must be a weak task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that there is unlikely to be any strong reference cycle here. But given how often block properties are sources for accidental strong reference cycles, often the question is not "why use weak", but rather "do I need a strong reference?" Yes, there is some modest overhead to using weak references, but it is a good defensive programming technique to examine the [object graph](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and ask oneself whether a strong reference is needed/desired.

In this case, if the task is complete, there's no reason for the progress blocks to maintain a strong reference to the task. So it's perfectly reasonable to use weak reference.